# Magento Tree Node Collection

Tags: php, magento

I am looking for someone that can explain the concept of a "tree" a "node" and a "collection"
in terms of Magento specifics. For example, in the below code getStoreCategories() method will return an instance of Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection which is enumerable and $child will be an object of type Varien_Data_Tree_Node. I'm asking in general, what does Magento mean by Tree, Node, and Collection.

```
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeCategories[] = $child;
            }

        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

collection - plain data, without nesting.
tree - data, that can be nested.
node - branch of the tree, can have its own branches.

Tree is used in categories, because categories can be nested one to each other. Products, orders, etc have plain structure, so no need to use nodes, just usual plain collection is used.

Answer (score 1):

Tree_Node_Collection is just referring to the hierarchical structure of the data.

Rather than being a flat collection (all items in a single queue for example) the data stored is hierarchical.

For example, with a category or menu structure each node can have sub tree's, which are essentially just more nodes with more children.

A collection has no notion of hierarchy, no parent child relationships etc.

The tree structure makes it a lot easier to iterate over, all children categories for example, including their children, many levels deep.